# Error in figure with subfigures in beamer missing value, treated as zero

Tags: beamer, floats

I'm trying to put into a beamer presentation on overleaf a graph that I already have in a document of class article.
However, it's not working. It says missing value, treated as 0 of line \end{frame}. Might be a package missing, but which one? Thanks!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} % new 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Distribution of $W$}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Distribution of the $W$ statistic} \label{w_c}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.7$} \label{w_c_1.7}
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{gini_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge_0_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge_1_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge_2_fim2.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.2$} \label{w_c_1.2}
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{gini_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge0_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge1_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth]{ge2_fim_12.pdf}
  \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use `subfigure`, it is obsolete package. instead it rather use `subcaption` package.
- In general the package `hypperref` had to be loaded last in preamble, however, the beamer document class already loaded it (see *samcarter* comment below), so it is no need tp load it again.
- The package `graphicx` is loaded by `beamer` document class too.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} % new
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Distribution of $W$}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Distribution of the $W$ statistic} \label{w_c}
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.7$} \label{w_c_1.7}
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{gini_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge_0_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge_1_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge_2_fim2.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}

  \bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.2$} \label{w_c_1.2}
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{gini_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge0_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge1_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm]{ge2_fim_12.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

- Option `demo` in  `\documentclass[demo]{beamer}` is passed to `graphics` package and in real document had to be removed. Here it is used because we haven't your actual images (it generate black squares instead them).

**Addendum:**

- Since all images are the same size, the figure code can be greatly shortened by using of the macro `\setkeys{Gin}{...}`:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption{Distribution of the $W$ statistic} \label{w_c}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.23\textwidth, height=22mm}    % <---
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.7$} \label{w_c_1.7}
  \includegraphics{gini_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge_0_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge_1_fim2.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge_2_fim2.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}

\bigskip
  \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
  \caption{Singh-Madalla with $c=1.2$} \label{w_c_1.2}
  \includegraphics{gini_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge0_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge1_fim12.pdf}\hfill
  \includegraphics{ge2_fim_12.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `beamer` already loads `hyperref`, so I would simply remove it. And instead of the `RequirePackage`, you can pass the option directly to beamer with `\documentclass[demo]{beamer}`

Comment: @samcarter, thank you to remains me. on this. It is a while when I last time check manual for Beamer ... and my presentations regarding figures are mostly simpler :). I correct my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That's it. Didn't know it was obsolete.